# Windows: Possible to have custom mouse profiles?

Tags: windows, mouse

I sometimes plug in my Wacom Bamboo tablet to my PC and I use the Wacom Bamboo mouse instead of the normal Microsoft mouse at those times. Now I would like to have different mouse settings for these 2 mice (settings like acceleration etc.)

Is there any way to create, maintain & apply such custom mouse profiles in Windows (XP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Might this be something useful for you?](http://www.themisteriosos.com/instantly-switch-between-two-different-mouse-speed-settings-on-laptop-with-shortcut-key.htm)

Comment: Answer is dead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is **"No"**. At least not in a default Windows set up.

However, there are tools to switch between settings, such as "Mouse Speed Switcher" - pointed out by [Stefan Thyberg](https://superuser.com/questions/5049/windows-possible-to-have-custom-mouse-profiles/5115#5115), which is available here: http://www.gphotoshow.com/mouse-speed-switcher.php

I've never used this software, or anything from that company, and can't vouch for it, but wanted to mention that such solutions exist.

Comment: Seems to work well.